# Looping in R to only add leading zeros to specified length

Tags: r

how would I be able to go from a column like this:
1
1
1
2
3
4
9
25
100

to one like this:
01
01
01
02
03
04
09
25
100

Basically, I want to add a leading zero to any value with only length 1. The actual data frame is much bigger than this. Thanks!

Comment: Try with `stringr::str_pad(1:100, width = 2, pad = "0")`.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `sprintf` in base R

```r
vec <-  c(1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 9, 25, 100)

sprintf("%02d", vec)
#> [1] "01"  "01"  "01"  "02"  "03"  "04"  "09"  "25"  "100"
```

Answer (score 3):

As an alternative `str_pad` from `stringr` package:

```
library(stringr)
str_pad(vec, 2, pad = "0")
```

```
[1] "01"  "01"  "01"  "02"  "03"  "04"  "09"  "25"  "100"
```

Answer (score 0):

You may also want to explore the [`formatC`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/formatC) function:

```
vec <-  c(1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 9, 25, 100)
formatC(x = vec, digits = 1, flag = "0", format = "d")
```

#### Results

```
"01"  "01"  "01"  "02"  "03"  "04"  "09"  "25"  "100"
```